# Drupal 7 Ubercart Rest Services Module (API)

Tags: 7, ubercart, services

I'm looking for the best way to retrieve Ubercart orders and customers from a remote server.
I'd like to plug in a connector the same way it works with Magento.
I've played a little bit with [Services](http://www.drupal.org/project/services) but didn't figure out how it works with Ubercart.

Does anybody knows where I can find the right module and documentation ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Bee Colony - Ubercart synchronization Web Service](http://drupal.org/project/bee_colony/) module.

> Bee Colony is a communication service (based on services module) for Ubercart based sites. Bee Colony allows site administrator to provide full remote control over Ubercart orders and products.
>
> Main objective is to build a client/server system to allow external software to synchronize its database with Ubercart.
>
> This project mission is to evolve Bee Colony to provide an easy and powerful way to create client-side software for companies and promote in this way Ubercart use.